# CSV find blank value in third column KSH

Tags: shell, awk, grep, ksh

Hi my data set is simple as show below

```
4,a,1.5
t,6,,
6,t,h
```

I am trying to use awk or grep to count the rows in which there is a blank in the third colmn. In this case it would be 1 since only the middle one has a blank in the column so far what i have tried is below. The login is trying to use awk to search for a blank string then count it the same with grep find where there is a blank in the third column then count it.

```
COUNT=$('awk '' $DATAFILE | wc -l')
COUNT=$('grep -e '.*,.*,,' $DATAFILE' | wc -l)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F, '$3==""{c++} END{print c+0}' file
```

Comment: I should have added one thing. This is in a script. so $3 is already being used by a variable being passed into the script. how can i change it so that it is not searing for that parameter. This works perfectly in the command line but not in my script

Comment: $3 in an awk script is the 3rd field in the input. It has nothing to do with the shell positional parameter that coincidentally is also named $3. You'll have to be clearer about what problem you are experiencing.

Comment: in the script i have count=$"( awk -F, '$3==""{c++} END{print c+0}' $DATAFILE )". When it runs it puts my scripts $3 in where it has the $3 in the command you showed me.

Comment: using set -x it gives something similar + COUNT=$( awk -F, 'SCRIPTS$3=={c++} END{print c+0}' file ) where SCRIPTS$3 is the third parameter that is being passed into the script.

Comment: Do you mean `"$(...)"` or do you actually have `$"(...)"`. The former is common, valid syntax, idk what the latter will do.

Comment: oh thanks for pointing that out. I pasted it into a syntax  checker and it didn't throw an error. It totally overlooked that.

Comment: So it must be valid syntax for something, just not the semantics you want. You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Your grep has to much quotes:

```
count=$(grep -E ".*,.*,," $DATAFILE | wc -l)
```

would work a bit, but you do not want to match a line with an emty fourth field.

Better seems to be

```
count=$(grep -E "^[^,]*,[^,]*,," $DATAFILE | wc -l)
```

This will still give problems with input like

```
field1,"field 2 with , insides quotes",,
```

Your question said nothing about this situation, what do you consider to be the third field here? That would be another question.

Edit:
@Sundeep commented correctly, that you could use the `grep -c`, avoiding `wc -l`. I tried to show what was wrong in the OP's answer, but I should have added the advice to use `-c`.

Comment: The third field is a decimal number or a blank. The first two fields are static and the third is a decimal that is merged onto the end of the lines. they want to know how many have a decimal number in the third field. Also there are quotes around the strings in the first two columns.

Comment: why not use `-c` option? for ex: `grep -c '^[^,]*,[^,]*,,'`